# How can I add transition animations to my existing onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I basically have a list of buttons on my page that include different amounts of hyperlink contents. I already have the basic styling and the script to enable display of these "drop down elements". I want to add some animation to it so that it looks smooth as the display is enabled and disabled. Maybe something that makes it looks like the elements are dropping down from the button.

I've looked up some answers from sof but no luck.
I achieved the enabling display part using event listeners, so I wanted to know if it's possible to combine my existing code that includes event listeners with this type of simple animation.

Note: I am new to building web pages so you can assume I don't know anything in the answers. Thank you!

Here is what my javascript code looks like (it might include unnecessary lines, that's because i was trying out some stuff):

```
var previousPage = null;
var currentPage = null;

function dropDown(dropdownId) {
    var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");
    var dropdownContent = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
    
    // close the open dropdowns on other dropdown clicks
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++) {
        var dropdown = dropdownContents[i];
        if (dropdown.classList.contains('show') && dropdown !== dropdownContent) {
            dropdown.classList.remove('show');   
        }

    }

    dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if (event.key === 'Escape'){
        var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");

        for (let i=0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++){
            dropdownContent = dropdownContents[i];
            if (dropdownContent.classList.contains('show')){
                if (!dropdownContents[i].contains(event.target)){
                    dropdownContents[i].classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        pass;
    }
});

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++) {
            var dropdownContent = dropdownContents[i];
            if (dropdownContent.classList.contains('show') && !dropdownContent.contains(event.target)) {
                dropdownContent.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }

    if (event.target.matches('.page')) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (event.target === currentPage) {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = '';
            currentPage = null;
        } else {
            if (currentPage) {
                currentPage.style.backgroundColor = '';
            }
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'orangered';
            currentPage = event.target;
        }
    }
});

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");

    for (var i = 0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++) {
        var dropdownContent = dropdownContents[i];
        var links = dropdownContent.getElementsByTagName("a");

        // convert html to array
        var linksArray = Array.from(links);

        // numeric and alphanumeric comparison
        linksArray.sort(function(a, b) {
            var textA = a.textContent;
            var textB = b.textContent;

            // check if text ends with number
            var regex = /\d+$/;
            var matchA = textA.match(regex);
            var matchB = textB.match(regex);

            if (matchA && matchB) {
                // compare numbers
                var numberA = parseInt(matchA[0]);
                var numberB = parseInt(matchB[0]);
                if (numberA === numberB) {
                    // if numbers are equal, sort alphabetically
                    var remainingTextA = textA.slice(0, matchA.index).trim();
                    var remainingTextB = textB.slice(0, matchB.index).trim();
                    return remainingTextA.localeCompare(remainingTextB);
                } else {
                    return numberA - numberB;
                }
            } else {
                return textA.localeCompare(textB);
            }
        });

        // clear existing links to prevent bulk
        while (dropdownContent.firstChild) {
            dropdownContent.firstChild.remove();
        }

        // add back sorted links to dropdown
        for (var j = 0; j < linksArray.length; j++) {
            dropdownContent.appendChild(linksArray[j]);
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/* dropdown button */
.dropbtn {
   
  color: black;
  background-color: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content{
  display:grid;
} */


/* position dropdown content on <div> */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  height: 22.5px;
}

/* dropdown content */
.dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color:orange;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 225px;
  z-index: 1; 
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: max-height .7s ease;
}

/* anchors */
.dropdown_content a {
  color: black;
  border-top: .5px solid black;
  border-bottom: .5px solid black;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

/* change color of elements on mouse hover */
.dropdown_content a:hover {
  background-color:orangered;
}

/* display style of dropdown menu */
.show {
  display:grid;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You will get more suggestions if you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example showing the changes you want to animate. As far as I can see from your long listing, you are adding and removing elements from the dom and so there are no css changes to animate. Remember transitions work on css properties or classes changing not on dom rendering. In general, you should use css to change appearance (to hide or show) your elements and apply transitions to those styles either by class switching or modifying css properties, in your case using js events.

Comment: Thank you! For now I got something close to what I wanted using "@keyframes unfold". I'm not sure if that relates to what you suggested, but thank you for your answer!